# FTP passive session creation:Destination unreachable (Host administratively prohibited)

Tags: ftp

When sending a "ls" command in ftp to the FTP server I get this message "No route to connect". So I investigated with wireshark and I could see the following exchange between me (the client) and the FTP server:

1) Client (32990) => Server Request PASV (21)

2) Server (21) => Client (32990) : Entering Passive Mode (10,11,1,8,66,76)

3) Client (32990) => Server (21) :ACK

4) Client (52974) => Server (16972) :SYN

5) Server => Client : Destination Unreachable (Host admin...)

Where 16972 (=256*66+76) is the data port of the server sent by this latter to the client on step 2.

52974 is the data port of the client.

So my question is: how do I know what prevents the passive session from being created ? Is it the server side ? client side ?

p.s: My client is on Kali, and everything is open in iptables
     I can't tell the configuration of the server (I don't have access to it directly)

Comment: Not the answer but wanted to provide for a good read on this topic of active versus passive FTP: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html. . .

Comment: Per that article as FYI... **Active FTP is beneficial to the FTP server admin, but detrimental to the client side admin. The FTP server attempts to make connections to random high ports on the client, which would almost certainly be blocked by a firewall on the client side. Passive FTP is beneficial to the client, but detrimental to the FTP server admin. The client will make both connections to the server, but one of them will be to a random high port, which would almost certainly be blocked by a firewall on the server side.**

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Thanks, I'm addon I changed account to ask another question :), so I guess it's better if I use Active mode because I don't know the configuration of the server and I can change mine, but when I type "ls" command in active mode (passive mode off), I'm getting "200 Port command successful. Consider using PASV".